# SQL Server insert error because of key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'X_dbo.XYZ'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object ...

I am sure it is not caused by a duplicate key !

I know that SQL Server is using a "mechanism" to insert the default key when you add a row (in my case an int).

After I delete all the rows in a table and then I try to add a row by specifying for id a value that previously was in that table I get this error.

I believe this is caused by this "mechanism" that I don't fully understand

For example I have in table XYZ a row

```
Id     Name
 1     "some name"
```

I delete this row then I try to add a new row with 1 as Id

```
INSERT .... 
VALUES (1, 'some other name for new row')
```

and I get this error.

Not specifying the id in insert is not an option for me, I need a work around or this error.

Thanks!

**UPDATED**

I table is created using Entity Framework and code-first approach (C#)

```
[Table("XYZ")]
public class XYZ: InheritDb
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    //....
}
```

and the insert script is like

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[XYZ] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[XYZ] ([ID], [Key], [Value], [Description], ...) 
VALUES (1, N'PaymentMode', N'Test', N'PaymentMode', ...)
```

Comment: Show us the create table statement, and the insert statements.

Comment: Is there some trigger active? Are you sure that this doesn't com from another table?

Comment: Also Show Delete script

Comment: Delete is simple just  ( Delete * From XYZ ) nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have auto-incrementing set on your table, even if you delete the record, the table does not reset the next row number it is going to insert.  So if you insert 1 row, that will get ID = 1.  If you delete that row and add a new row, that new row will be ID = 2 even though 1 no longer exists.  In order to reset that, use the following command

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ([dbo].[XYZ], RESEED, 0)
```

Comment: I was hoping to not drop the table. If there is a way to reset this next id number, it would be ideal.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

if you set Id is **'Identity Column'** you, don't insert row with old Id.
for insert you must in Properties tab, in Table Designer, set **'Identity Column'** is ' '.